# (Github) "Testing your SSH connection" -> host key verification failed

Tags: github, ssh

I followed [setting-up-git guide](https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/foundations/courses/foundations/lessons/setting-up-git). It didn't work.
I also tried to follow the GitHub's [connecting-to-github-with-ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) guide. It didn't work either.
I keep getting same error :

`host key verification failed.`

After googling found this suggestion: `ssh-keygen -R hostname`.

Tried replacing `hostname` with `github.com` and `13.234.176.102`.

Still same result : `do_known_hosts: hostkeys_foreach failed: No such file or directory`.

The **.ssh** diirectory cotains below files:

```
id_ed25519
id_ed25519.pub
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```

**OS**:- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing, try and:

- rename/remove your existing ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- try again `ssh -Tv git@github.com` and answer 'yes' when prompted

From there, the test should work.

Comment: The `known_hosts` file doesn't exist. I think it was never created, because I never saw it.

Comment: @MayankTiwari It will be created for you at your first `ssh -Tv git@github.com`

Comment: `Host key verification failed.` again. But, this time the output is longer. Should I edit the question and add the entire output?

Comment: @MayankTiwari Yes (or reference the content to an external pastbin service if it is too big)

Comment: I'm so sorry. I pressed enter, instead of typing 'yes'. It works now. `Hi mayank996! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` Thank you.